# Jest - run coverage report for all files in the project?

Tags: jestjs

I want to run a coverage report for all files in my code repo, including those that currently don't have any tests.

I'm using this command:

```
jest --coverage --collectCoverageFrom='src/features/**/*.{ts,tsx}
```

But there are other folders i want to cover.
Is it not possible to "tell" Jest to look at **all** `.ts` and `.tsx` files across all folders, including nested folders?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The command you have should generate coverage report for **all** `.ts` and `.tsx` inside the the folders in `src/features` folder.

If you want to include other folders, for example everything inside `/src` then use

```bash
jest --coverage --collectCoverageFrom='src/**/*.{ts,tsx}'
```

Comment: Yes, i'm aware i can specify it this way. My question was id i could do something like `--collectCoverageFrom='src/*` or whatever and it would find **all** files across **all** nested folders, so something like `src/folder/component.tsx` but also `src/folder1/folder2/folder3/component.tsx`

Comment: Yes, using the code snippet I included should find all files with the extensions `ts` and `jxs` inside `src` regardless of how nested they are.

Comment: pattern should contain "jsx" not "jxs"

jest --coverage --collectCoverageFrom='src/**/*.{js,jsx}'